# Calculating where two bank accounts with different interest rates will be equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So in class we were given two examples of different bank accounts with different interest rates. The first is compounded twice a year and has an interest rate of $10\%$. The second has an initial fee of 1 dollar but it compounded continuously at an interest rate of $9.8\%$. I came up with the following equations for the two accounts.

Account 1: $m(t)=10(1+0.1)^t$

Account 2: $m(t)=9e^{0.098t}$

To solve when the bank accounts meet and how many years it will take for one to pass the other, I know to set the two equations equal and solve for t. However, I am able to get it down to $\ln(10/9(1.1)^t) = 0.098t$ but I am unsure of how to go any further. How would I go about finishing solving for t or using a different method? I have to do it mathematically and can't just find the intersection point with a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

$m_1(t):=10(1+0.1)^t$ and $m_2(t):=9e^{0.098t}$ are the given expressions. Considering their intersection we have:
$$m_1(t)=m_2(t)\\10(1.1)^t=9e^{0.098t}\\\frac{1.1^t}{e^{0.098t}}=\frac{9}{10}\\\left(\frac{1.1}{e^{0.098}}\right)^t=\frac{9}{10}$$
take logarithms of both sides.